# Binding views in android using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Whats the difference between the below two ways of binding views in android using kotlin?And which one is better?

```
TextView tvSelectDistance=findViewById<View>(R.id.tvSelectDistance) as TextView
```

vs

```
TextView tvSelectDistance=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvSelectDistance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use android kotlin ktx plugin to simplify this more.
add this to your build.gradle: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

when you will use this plugin you will need not to find the view by yourselft, just do as following :

```
// Instead of findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
textView.setText("Hello, world!")
```

For more follow this [URL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

**For your questions :**

In Android, `findViewById` returns a `View` we need to explicitly cast to the correct type(you are doing this with your first approach).

In your second approach, you provide a type which is TextView to findViewById so there will be no need to type cast it.

Comment: *In Android, findViewById returns a View* - this is not true anymore. From api 26 and up, it returns `T` where T is `<T extends View>`

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of *Android* `findViewById()` was defined as

```
public View findViewById(@IdRes int id)
```

so it was necessary to cast it to the proper type.

With the current version it is defined as

```
public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id)
```

which just casts the found view implicitly with the call.

Thus the following options

```
TextView tvSelectDistance = findViewById<View>(R.id.tvSelectDistance) as TextView
TextView tvSelectDistance = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvSelectDistance)
TextView tvSelectDistance = findViewById(R.id.tvSelectDistance)
```

are technically equivalent. But instead of casting the return value explicitly, you can use the latter two and have some neater code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be correct way:

```
val selectDistanceText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tvSelectDistance)
```